# PHP Conditionals --> If Else with multiple decisions

Tags: php, conditional-statements

if I have something like:

```
if (($browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_SAFARI && $browser->getVersion() >= 3 ) ||
    ($browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_CHROME && $browser->getVersion() >= 5 ))
{
    // code here
}
```

but I really want to say also if Chrome >= 5 but less 6...

I will add an else if for 6+

later on in else () less than version 5 would fall into..

How would I write >= 5 but < 6?

Comment: How could something be greater than `5` but less than `6`?

Comment: @Jacob: Not all numbers are integers

Comment: @Jacob - 5.1 or 5.1 or 5.3 or 5.4 or 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can do this directly by adding another condition:

```
if (($browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_SAFARI 
     && $browser->getVersion() >= 3 ) ||
    ($browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_CHROME 
     && $browser->getVersion() >= 5 && $browser->getVersion() < 6 ))
{
    // code here
}
```

I'm assuming `getVersion` must be capable of returning non-integer numbers, otherwise you could just check for equality (`$browser->getVersion() == 5`).

Comment: Good points here. Yes, it does return 3.5, 5.5, etc. Thanks. Makes sense.